# Problema ao usar if e elif Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Estou com um problema ao utilizar o `if` e o `elif` para criar uma tabela de extrato pegando informações do banco.

Caso no banco a categoria da transação for depósito, eu quero que ele `print` de uma maneira, porém depois que ele passou do primeiro `if`, caso tenha algum outro item que se encaixe nessa condição, ele não está recebendo as condições propostas do `if` que criei.

Segue o exemplo do código e do retorno na tela.

```
idtransacao = cursor.execute('SELECT id_transacao FROM extrato WHERE id_extrato = ?',(vnconta,))
for f in idtransacao:
    x = f
    x = str(x).strip("(,)")
    listaid.append(x)
ctdr = len(listaid)
contador = 0
print('''
Codigo da transacao |   Categoria   | Destino  |   Valor    |     Data     |
------------------- |-------------- |--------- | ---------- | ------------ |''')
while contador != ctdr:
    if listacat[contador] == 'DEPOSITO':
        if len(listaval[contador]) <= 3:
            print(' '*12 + '{}'.format(listaid[contador])+' '*11+'|'+' '*2 + '{}'.format(listacat[contador])+' '*5 + '|' + ' '*2 + '----' +' '*4+ '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listaval[contador] + ' '*7 + '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listadate[contador] + ' '*2 + '|')))
            contador += 1
        elif len(listaval[contador]) <= 2:
            print(' '*12 + '{}'.format(listaid[contador])+' '*11+'|'+' '*2 + '{}'.format(listacat[contador])+' '*5 + '|' + ' '*2 + '----' +' '*4+ '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listaval[contador] + ' '*8 + '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listadate[contador] + ' '*2 + '|')))     
    elif listacat[contador] == 'SAQUE':
        print(' '*12 + '{}'.format(listaid[contador])+' '*11+'|'+' '*2 + '{}'.format(listacat[contador])+' '*8 + '|' + ' '*2 + '----' +' '*4+ '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listaval[contador] + ' '*7 + '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listadate[contador] + ' '*2 + '|')))
        contador += 1
    elif listacat[contador] == 'TRANSFERENCIA':
        print(' '*12 + '{}'.format(listaid[contador])+' '*11+'|'+' '*2 + '{}'.format(listacat[contador]) + '|' + ' '*4 + '{}'.format(listadet[contador]) +' '*5+ '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listaval[contador] + ' '*7 + '|' + ' '*2 + '{}'.format(listadate[contador] + ' '*2 + '|')))
        contador += 1
```

```
===============================================================================
Codigo da transacao |   Categoria   | Destino  |   Valor    |     Data     |
------------------- |-------------- |--------- | ---------- | ------------ |
        1           |  DEPOSITO     |  ----    |  100       |  2018-12-06  |
        2           |  SAQUE        |  ----    |  200       |  2018-12-11  |
        3           |  DEPOSITO     |  ----    |  600       |  2018-12-06  |
        4           |  SAQUE        |  ----    |  200       |  2018-12-11  |
        5           |  TRANSFERENCIA|    2     |  10       |  2018-12-06  |
        6           |  DEPOSITO     |  ----    |  10       |  2018-12-06  | <<<- deveria pegar o if igual ao codigo da transacao '1'
```

Comment: Para quem esta de fora do contexto ficou meio confusa a sua questão, da para vc dar um `print(listaid)` e mostrar o resultado na pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que você está alterando a variável 'contador' antes de usar ela inteiramente. Veja que dentro do loop, após o segundo 'if' você altera 'contador'. Na linha seguinte você utiliza 'listaval[contador]' e agora já não está usando a mesma informação que antes, pois o contador foi incrementado.

Não vou sugerir uma alteração no seu código diretamente, pois não dá pra saber como ele tem que funcionar no fim. Me parece, no entanto, que você precisaria ou de dois contadores ou deixar para incrementá-lo ao fim do 'while'.